# Prove or provide a counter example to "there exists a real number x, such that for all real numbers y, x+y<0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am currently learning about proofs and propositional logic and have covered negation of statements, proof by contradiction and by counterexample.

I'm pretty sure the proposition is false as there cannot b a single number that reduces every single real number to less than 0, however, I do not know how to construct a proof for this. The question just says give proof or counterexample.

Any advice?

Comment: take $y = -x+1$ for counter example.

Comment: What exactly would be a counterexample to a statement of the form "there exists ..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let this $x$ exists.

Thus, for $y=-x+1$ we obtain:
$$x+y=x-x+1=1>0,$$ which is contradiction.

Thus, the statement is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "proof by contradiction".  Suppose there exist such a number, x.  Let y= -x+ 1. Clearly x+ y is NOT less than 0.

The previous answer, which was deleted, was misinterpreting the question as "show that for any y there exist x" while it was, in fact, "there exist x that works for **all** y".

Comment: Can you give me some help in understanding this because this is exactly what I am getting confused upon. Suppose the question was the other way round, i.e. "For any x, there exists a y, such that x+y<0" =, what can you do instead? In both cases are you just allowed to assign a value to y, e.g. -x +1 or does it differ upon the order of the proposition (for all, there exists vs there exists, for all)

Comment: Given y, if x+ y< 0, then x< -y.  That is sufficient.  However, the original problem asked for a single value of x such that x+ y< 0 for [b]all[/b] y. That is not possible.